# How to display String variables recieved from a servlet into a form text field of JSP

Tags: jsp

I have created a servlet that passes a string variable strname to a JSP page.
The JSP recieves it into a variable "strname" using

```
request.getAttribute("strname")
```

Now I want to display this inside the text field of a form

```
 <form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
            <% String strname =(String)request.getAttribute("uname");%> 
            Username:<input type="text" name="username" value="${username}"/>
    </form>
```

but it is displaying "username" int the text field.
How can I display the strname var in the text ??
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$` you can get the value. For ex :
 `<input type="text" name="strname" value="${strname}" />` 
(Assuming you are getting correct value in strname variable.)

Comment: <% String username =(String)request.getAttribute("strname");%> 
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="${username}" />

NOT WORKING

Comment: Use this :- `<%=request.getAttribute("whatevername")%>`

Answer (score 2):

You may use EL expression (read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)).

```
<input type="text"
       value="${requestScope.strname}"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text"
       value="${strname}"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text"
       value="${param.username}"/>
```

or JSTL `<c:out />`

```
 <c:out value="${strname}"/>
```

Comment: here is the entire form:

    <form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
    <% String username = request.getAttribute("uname").toString();%> 
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="${username}"     readonly="readonly" />
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jstl way to get the value stores in the request e.g

`<input type="text" value="${uname}">`